# Config: Missing name WorldDatabaseInfo in config

Tags: windows, docker, azerothcore

Just did a "git pull" to check for new updates on an install of wow via docker (windows)
But these errors came up when trying to start the server.
'''
ac-worldserver_1  | > Config: Missing name PidFile in config, add "PidFile = "
ac-worldserver_1  | > Config: Missing name WorldDatabaseInfo in config, add "WorldDatabaseInfo = "
ac-worldserver_1  | World database not specified in configuration file
'''
I am not sure how to fix this, I have been regularly updating the server with zero issue, now this popped up to me today (Feb. 28, 2020)

Answer (score 1):

Configs path has been changed to

- In Windows (./configs) and (./configs/modules)
- In non Windows (./etc/) and (./etc/modules)

Check PR for more info https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/4608

Comment: thank you for the response.
this did not solve my problem though, i updated the config paths as you stated but im still getting these errors when trying to start the server up

ac-worldserver_1  | > Config: Missing name PidFile in config, add "PidFile = "
ac-worldserver_1  | > Config: Missing name WorldDatabaseInfo in config, add "WorldDatabaseInfo = "
ac-worldserver_1  | World database not specified in configuration file

Comment: also i tried building a new fresh acore, using docker for windows, new build does not script the changes to the config paths either, its broken

Comment: what path do you have your worldserver.conf and worldserver.conf.dist files located at?

Comment: azerothcore/configs (new setting)
previous it was:
azerothcore/docker/worldserver/etc (old setting)

Comment: the docker containers run linux so the conf files should be in docker/worldserver/etc still. What operating system are you running docker on?

Comment: im running windows 10 pro and using docker for my install method